# Re-using an API key for several different APIs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

My AWS solution has several different APIs, each implemented using an API Gateway.
Now I want to introduce usage plans with throttling, and I want to use the fact that API keys can be assigned by an authorizer lambda.
However, I'm very confused regarding the relations between API keys, APIs, stages and usage plans.

1. A usage plan is associated with 1-N API+stage tuples. That's fine, so I can define a plan once with throttling of X requests per day, and apply that same constraint to 3 different APIs.
2. A UsagePlanKey ties 1 API key to 1 usage plan. Nothing strange.

With this in mind I thought about creating one single API key `SharedApiKey`, and then for each API set up a usage plan for that API only, and associate each usage plan with the same API key `SharedApiKey`:

Resources:

```
Shared:
SharedApiKey (AWS:ApiGateway::Key)

For API 1:
Api1 (AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi)
Api1Stage (AWS::ApiGateway::Stage)
Api1UsagePlan (AWS::ApiGateway::UsagePlan) - connect to Api1+Api1Stage
Api1UsagePlanKey - connect Api1UsagePlan with SharedApiKey

etc for API 2, 3, 4...
```

I thought this would mean that I could create the shared API key in its own CF stack, and then have each API CF stack associate its usage plan with it.

However, then I found that the API key resources themselves *also* have an array of associations to API+stage tuples. Why is that? It seems redundant to have keys connected to N API stages, and usage plans connected to N API stages, and UsagePlanKeys connecting 1 UsagePlan to 1 key?

I then found that `StageKeys` on ApiKey is optional, so perhaps this is simply a legacy attribute? Or what is the consequence of not associating a key with any APIs or stages, and only connect keys to usage plans the other way around?

Will my intended setup work at all?

Comment: The wording is a bit unclear - do you have some code to show please? `API key resources themselves also have an array of associations to API+stage tuples` - what do you exactly mean? Is this only an issue when using CF? Is your question regarding `StageKeys`? What's the actual question here?

Comment: Yes, my question is partly about `StageKeys` - what is the purpose of it when a key is then bound to one or more usage plans as well? It seems redundant. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-apikey.html#cfn-apigateway-apikey-stagekeys